# Looping through Dictionary items in iTextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

This method us to work now after switching to AWS I get a weird error:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetFormFieldNames(string pdfPath)
{
    var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader.AcroFields.Fields)
    {
        fields.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), string.Empty);
    }

    return fields;
}
```

> Cannont convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<String.iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.item>`
>   to `System.CollectionsEntry`

I understand the error is apparent but i can't seem to get the type right. Why would this method stop working? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you use var (in place of DictionaryEntry), and then use intellisense to get the correct value into your dictionary?

Comment: @thinklarge I did what you suggested and that worked thanks! If you make it an answer I will mark it as answered. I can't imagine how many itext users could be having this issue now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I love the tooling around C# for this reason.  Intellisense makes the learning curve for new libraries much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use var instead of a type definition and then get Intellisence to complete for you.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetFormFieldNames(string pdfPath)
{
    var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var entry in reader.AcroFields.Fields)
    {
        fields.Add(entry.*use intellisense here*, string.Empty);
    }

    return fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message makes no sense. A KeyValuePair has two type parameters, but the message you've posted has only one. There's also no System.CollectionsEntry type or namespace in .NET, so I suspect you've truncated your actual error message. In any case, I'm guessing the type of Fields is a System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item>. You could just use foreach (var kvp in reader.AcroFields.Fields).

As to why things "changed," perhaps you changed .NET versions? DictionaryEntry is the pre-generics way of iterating over Hashtables.